# Why should absolute imports come before relative imports?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm importing some resources in my Vue file. The fact that it's Vue, though, have nothing to do with my question, I believe.

I import them as such:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'
import ChessPiece from '../assets/classes/chesspiece'
import 'vue-awesome/icons/rotate-left'
import 'vue-awesome/icons/search'
```

ESLint then tells me:

> Absolute imports should come before relative imports

I'm just wondering, why is this?

Comment: It probably the linter preference https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md

Comment: probably a carry-over or as a result from/of eslint-config-airbnb.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just an coding convention to make everything cleaner.

Usually absolute imports comes from external library, and relative imports from your code.

Comment: Along the same lines, the angular style guide talks about "separating your stuff from their stuff": https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#import-line-spacing.